# Rancher Dashboard port is already in use 443 and 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rancher, rancher-rke

My rancher dashboard pod was crashed and when I am running docker run command to install rancher it's throwing error that port is already in use 443 and 80 when I check it's used by nginx: master

When I am typing kubectl get ns it's throwing error Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not xyz.com

it's Very Important to fix this and keep my rancher dashboard up and running. How do I fix this issue?
I need your help (Production server)
Looking forward to getting quick help.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I have fixed the Issue :)

Comment: Can you describe how you solved the problem and what was the cause ?
It may be helpful for other community members.